# Can i install internet explorer without internet connectivity?

Tags: web, browser, internet-explorer-11

I need to install internet explorer 11 on some systems and do not have internet access on the same.How do i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need an offline installer though. Check https://www.itechtics.com/download-internet-explorer-all-versions/

Comment: the provided link was not helpful;it still asks for downloading updates from internet.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later, no answer.

However,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11e3314b-9089-443a-832d-1f9ab06ac0b8/internet-explorer-11-installation-without-internet-access

is perhaps helpful. I quote:

> There are many updates which are deemed pre-requisite for IE11.
>
> You can check the `c:\windows\IE11_MAIN.log` logfile, which is a record of the IE11 installation attempt, this may reveal missing pre-requisites..

Or even `IE10_main.log`

You could find the failed KB updates and download them on a PC with internet access, being sure to match the OS of the disconnected PC, not the current one, and then move them to the disconnected PC and install them manually.

This worked for me 03/30/2020 on a windows 7 pc that had had no updates since 2012. I was trying to install IE10. Filename: `IE10-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe`. My prerequisites were:

```
00:41.371: INFO:    Download for KB2670838 initiated. Downloading http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272391 -> KB2670838_amd64.CAB.
00:41.434: INFO:    Download for KB2786081 initiated. Downloading http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=273751 -> KB2786081_amd64.CAB.
00:41.668: INFO:    Waiting for 2 prerequisite downloads.
```

Interestingly, when I tried to run the installers I got by looking up the KB numbers and downloadeding from microsoft, one said not applicable to this computer. [I now realize I had the wrong one for the first one, and the 2nd one said not applicable to this computer, so perhaps if I had downloaded the right one and installed them in order it would have worked.]

I had to follow those go.microsoft fwlink URLs, download those `.cab` files and use the technique here: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/install-cab-msu-updates-mu-catalog/ and I quote:

> Installing .CAB Updates (non-drivers)
>
> To apply the CAB update, you need to use DISM, which is short for
>   Deployment Image Servicing and Management Tool.
>
> Open an elevated or Admin Command Prompt window, and type:
>
> `dism /online /add-package /packagepath:"cab_package_path"`
>
> Example
>
> `dism /online /add-package /packagepath:"f:\wucatalog\windows10.0-kb3194496-x64.cab"`

That satisfied the IE10 installer and I got this happy logfile entry:

```
00:56.332: INFO:    Waiting for 0 prerequisite downloads.
```